# jquery get data-id from li

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I need to get the `data-id` from an href click in a `li`.
But the ul, li and href do not have ids.
They do have long class names.
For example:

```
<ul class="a-long class-name">
   <li class="a-long-li class-name" data-id="99">
      <div class="generic-button">
         <a href="#" class="button edit edit-item secondary-action my-tooltip"> 
            <span class="edit-label">Edit</span>
         </a>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How would I get the `data-id` when the href is clicked in that `li` ?

I cannot change any of the elements or attributes or add to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `data-id` attribute as part of the selector

```js
$('li[data-id] a').click(function(e){
   const id = $(this).closest('li').data('id');
   console.log('ID:', id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="a-long class-name">
   <li class="a-long-li class-name" data-id="99">
      <div class="generic-button">
         <a href="#" class="button edit edit-item secondary-action my-tooltip"> 
            <span class="edit-label">Edit</span>
         </a>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```